# Weird behavior in GetElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript, dom

I've tried to get an array of pictures to create an simple carousel.
When I try to change the classname to show or hide some elements my array is modified I don't know why...

This is my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/op1nzkxc/

HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="my-carousel">
    <div>
        <div class="car-hide">Picture 1</div>
        <div class="car-hide">Picture 2</div>
        <div class="car-hide">Picture 3</div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript :

```
pictures = [];

function getAllElementsHidden(){
    return document.getElementsByClassName("car-hide");
}

function startSlide(){
    pictures = getAllElementsHidden();
    console.log(pictures);
    pictures[1].className = "car-show";
    console.log(pictures);
}

startSlide();
```

CSS :

```
body{
    text-align: center;
}

ul{
    text-decoration: none;
}

.car-hide{
    display: none;
}
```

Can someone help me please?

Comment: You could use more semantic HTML:

    <div id="my-carousel"><ul>
        <li>Picture 1</li>
        <li>Picture 2</li>
        <li>Picture 3</li>
    </ul></div>

and select items without relying on class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.getElementsByClassName` returns a *live collection* of elements. It is always up to date. If you remove a feature that made it qualify, then it is no longer present. If you need to keep an invariant collection of nodes for later, you need to duplicate it using `.slice`; however, since the live collection is not an `Array` but an array-like object, we need to take `Array`'s `.slice` and apply it on the live collection:

```
var pictures = Array.prototype.slice.call(getAllElementsHided())
```

Comment: Much simpler (in this case) to use *querySelectorAll* as it returns a static NodeList be default: `document.querySelectorAll('.car-hide')`.

Comment: @RobG: True. It seemed the main thrust of the question is "why it behaves like this"...